# How to extract hour from a series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried to extract the hour of day from a series column.

My data looks like this:

```
Unique Key  Created Date
32305299    2016-01-01 00:00:09
```

Which 'Created date' being series:

```
type(df['Created Date'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

I tried below but didn't work:

```
df['Created Date'].dt.hour
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

How can I extract the hour of day in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Need `df['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date'])`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael I tried to do this: df['Col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created Date']) but it seems can't change to datetime object? type(df['Col']) pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: No, need test it by `print (df['Col'].dtype)`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael!

Comment: you can use pd.DatetimeIndex 
`df['create_date_hour'] =pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Create Date']).hour`